# Highcharts tooltip format different with series

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am a beginner in Highcharts, I try to make the column charts with some data. The charts must be displayed like this :
[image]

but I have not succeeded. I really confused to try to display the tooltip like in the box, because the series only have 2 things (Rencana, Realisasi )but in the box shows 3 (Rencana, Realisasi, Indicator). 
and I have to try to format the tooltip like this :

```
{
  chart: {
      renderTo: 'gjenis',
      type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
      text: 'Bauran Energi per Jenis Bahan Bakar (TWh)'
  },
  subtitle: {
      text: ' '
  },
  xAxis: {
      categories: jenis,
      crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
          text: ' '
      }
  },
  tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
          '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.2f} TWh</b></td></tr>' + 
          '<tr><td>Indikator : </td>' +
          '<td><b>x %</b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: '</table> ',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
      column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 1
      }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Rencana',
      data: rencana,
      color: 'red'

  }, {
      name: 'Realisasi',
      data: realisasi,
      color: 'blue'

  }]
}
```

but the result in the box like this :
[image]

is there any function that can be displayed like the first image so it does not loop the "Indicator"? How to format the tooltip to be like the first one?

Thanks a lot for Your attention

Comment: please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [document](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter):

> Since version 2.1 the tooltip can be shared between multiple series through the shared option. The available data in the formatter differ a bit depending on whether the tooltip is shared or not. In a shared tooltip, all properties except x, which is common for all points, are kept in an array, this.points.

when you set `shared` property to `true`, then you can use custom `formatter` function and inside this function you can loop through your points and generate a custom tooltip( like what you want). for example:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = "<span style=\"font-size:10px\">" + this.x + "</span><table>"

        $.each(this.points, function () {
            s += "<tr><tdstyle=\"color:"+this.series.color+";padding:0\">"+this.series.name+": </td>" +
      "<td style=\"padding:0\"><b>"this.series.y+" TWh</b></td></tr>";
        });
        s += "<tr><td>Indikator : </td>"+ "<td><b>x %</b></td></tr></table>"
        return s;
    },
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
}
```

(please consider that the code is not tested and is just to give you an idea about what i mean.)

**EDIT**:
in the code I used `this.series.y` to access `y` value which is wrong and should be `this.y`:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = "<span style=\"font-size:10px\">" + this.x + "</span><table>"

        $.each(this.points, function () {
            s += "<tr><tdstyle=\"color:"+this.series.color+";padding:0\">"+this.series.name+": </td>" +
      "<td style=\"padding:0\"><b>"this.y+" TWh</b></td></tr>";
        });
        s += "<tr><td>Indikator : </td>"+ "<td><b>x %</b></td></tr></table>"
        return s;
    },
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
}
```